# Pass enum to another enum in a class to encapsulate it in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, enums

sorry I am not sure if this is going to make sense or if the title even makes sense.

So I am writing up aload of class libraries which can be used for various reason, obviously depending on what we would be creating would determine whether we need to create a reference to a class.

One thing to note is that we want to separate things up, hence this post. In a shared class in its own project lets say Letters and in there we have an enum

```
public enum enum1 
{
   A, 
   B, 
   C
}
```

In a different class library (lets called it Words) we are doing something which would use enum1, so we would reference the project Letters (dll). Now what I am trying to do is get away from having to reference Letters when we want to use Words. I effectively want to get to enums1 when referencing words. so for example

```
Words - referencing Letters
public Enum Characters {get { return Letters.enum1; } }

Letters
public enum enum1{
   A, B, C
}
  
App - Only reference Words
Words.Characters. 

and then the list of A, B, C
```

I know I could just change

```
public Enum Characters {get { return Letters.enum1; } }
```

to

```
public Words.enum1 Characters {get; }
```

but that would mean in my App i would need to reference both Words and Letters, which ideally i do not want as someone could reference words not needing letters at all.

Is this possible and how could this be accomplished.

Thanks

Comment: If Words references Letters then any client of Words has the intrinsic dependency on Letters. But that's what Nuget is for...

Comment: You're right, it doesn't make any sense. You're making this very complicated over having to reference an assembly, which is a non-issue.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield While i do agree and normally i would not entertain such an idea, however there is a reason to do this otherwise I would not have asked. Ultimately you are right it doesn't really matter in the grand scheme of things but unfortunately I am not the one making decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the usage scenario is:

- There are types that need to be shared (e.g. `enum1`).
- It is not desirable to put the types into their own assembly.
- The types are used in two or more assemblies that should never have dependencies on each other (e.g. `letters.dll` will never reference `words.dll` and vice versa).
- A consuming assembly should never depend on more than one of the assemblies with the shared types (e.g. `app.exe` will never references both `letters.dll` and `words.dll`).

then a possible solution is to use a 'Shared Project'.

In Visual Studio when creating a new project, filter for C# and search for `shared`.

A shared project doesn't really produce an output. But other projects that have a project reference to the shared project will include the source files from the shared project. In other words, there would be one source file for `enum1`; the source file would be in the shared project; and, by referencing the shared project, both `letters` and `words` would both have the same `enum1` type.

However, because it is the same type in the same namespace, if `app` tried to reference both `letters` and `words` there would be an error because the same type would exist in both assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid referring the Letters project directly in your App project, you can define a copy of the enum1 enum in the Words project and manually map the values from the original enum1 to the new copy of enum1. This is very unnecessary and a waste of energy, and probably doesn't quite do what you want. If you're not quite satisfied, please make a clear request for improvement.

Letters:

```
public enum enum1 {
   A, B, C
}
```

Words:

```
public enum Characters {
   A,
   B,
   C
}

public static class EnumMapper {
    public static Characters Map(enum1 value) {
        switch (value) {
            case enum1.A: return Characters.A;
            case enum1.B: return Characters.B;
            case enum1.C: return Characters.C;
            default: throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown value {value}");
        }
    }
}
```

App:

```
using Words;

var character = EnumMapper.Map(enum1.A); // Map from enum1 to Characters
```